# Using host visual studio license to run build tools in windows container?

Tags: windows, docker, visual-studio, containers

I have a windows server 2019 host that has licensed installation of Visual Studio 2019. I also have docker on the host machine and am building a container image. I want to access host VS build tools from within the container. Wondering if I can use the host's license key to use build tools within my container? I don't want to install build tools directly in my container, since I am having problems doing that and also I am not sure if I will break any licensing terms since I will basically create this docker image and make it available for others to use. If my docker run can verify that the host is licensed for Visual Studio, I can then mount build tools from host into container. But am not sure if this case is covered by the supplemental license. Please suggest

If the above is possible, do I mount the host's key from windows registry? Suggestions on how to have my docker read the host's registry key?

Comment: hi toast12, what did you end up doing, facing similar issue/challenge.